# Getting unknown error while fetching media item using powershell sitecore

Tags: powershell-extensions

I was trying to get media item using media ID. I am getting the below error which I haven't faced before in powershell sitecore.

**Scenario**

```
$ImageId - {61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223}
```

I am using the below command and getting below mentioned error:-

```
Get-Item -Path master: -ID $ImageId
```

**Error**

```
Get-Item : Expected hex 0x in '{0}'. Actual value: {61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223}
```

The same command is working fine in 2 more places, is this a PowerShell extension bug ?

Comment: For me the same command is working fine and returning results. COuld you check with any other image?

$ImageId = "{F2CE0A45-0187-4E36-8AEF-1185C1B74FAA}"

Get-Item -Path master: -ID $ImageId

Comment: `$item = Get-Item -Path "master:{path}" -Id "{6AA5AA9F-071A-4808-91AC-709FAAFFB310}"
$mediaItem = [Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem]$item`
Does this help?

Comment: I believe I was not able to explain the context properly, apologies. Firstly the ID which I am getting is {61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223} which is not in a valid format. Can I parse this ID to SItecore GUID format using powershell, the rest will work fine I believe.

Comment: yes, correct.. now I understand your question.
Did you try something like this :  `$parsedID = [Sitecore.Data.ID]$ImageId`?

Comment: I tried just now with this, it gives me this error  :-

Cannot convert value "{61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223}" to type "Sitecore.Data.ID". Error: "Expected hex 0x in '{0}'. Actual value: {61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is because the ID that you are trying to use is not in the proper format. One way to workaround this is to parse the id that you received without the `{` `}`. Please see code below

```
$id = [Sitecore.Data.ID]::Parse("110D559FDEA542EA9C1C8A5DF7E70EF9")
$item = Get-Item "master: -ID $id"
$item
```

The above code snippet will provide the below output

[image]

So, for your case, all you need to do at first is to remove the `{` `}` and then parse the value to the `ID.Parse` method.

**Update**

Below is a script snippet on replacing the `{` `}`

```
$ImageStringId = "{61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223}"

$updatedStringId = $ImageStringId.replace("{","")
$updatedStringId = $updatedStringId.replace("}","")

Write-Host "Updated Image String Id $updatedStringId"

$id = [Sitecore.Data.ID]::Parse($updatedStringId)

$item = Get-Item "master: -ID $id"
$item
```

Comment: Nice! $x needs to be changed to $id in line #2 I guess..

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean correct. Just updated the answer

Comment: I tried with this just now, its also giving me this below error :-

Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Expected hex 0x in '{0}'. Actual value: {61630AC1F0E3111B9C50CEEE0B2B0223}

Comment: @DivyanshGupta you need to remove the starting `{` and ending `}`

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, this works perfectly fine for me, Thank you for providing the solution. :)

Comment: @DivyanshGupta I updated the answer with the script snippet to remove the {}